# Trouble Inputting Doubles in View Due To Not Using Strings?

Tags: c#, xaml, types, converters

I have a View in which I should be able to input doubles. The thing is, I can only input whole numbers such as "100" but not "100.4". All my background calculations run on doubles though. Is there an easy fix?

View:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DelayModel.DelayTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Model:

```
    private double _delayTime;

    public double DelayTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _delayTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _delayTime)
            {
                _delayTime = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Another Model which uses `delayTime`:

```
public double TotalAxisTime
        {
            get
            {
                double positioningTime = 0.0;
                double delayTime = 0.0;

                foreach (var block in BlockList)
                {
                    if (block is PositioningModel)
                    {
                        positioningTime = positioningTime + ((PositioningModel)block).PositioningTime;
                    }

                    if (block is DelayModel)
                    {
                        delayTime = delayTime + ((DelayModel)block).DelayTime;
                    }
                }
                return (positioningTime + delayTime);
            }
        }
```

(PositioningTime is another double value which I probably need to convert to strings.

I'm struggling to implement the Convert.ToString()-Method. Is this the right approach? Should I use dedicated Converters in XAML? Something like StringToDoubleConverter with IValueConverter?

Any advice would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your trouble lies in the binding from double to string: whenever you edit the text in the textbox, the double value is updated and the update is reflected back the textbox. This works fine when you enter digits, say change "123" to "1234". But suppose that you then add a decimal point: "1234.". The value will just be treated as 1234 in the model and fail to pass the 'if (value != _delayTime)' check, thereby not being updated. The textbox will just keep showing the value 1234 due to the binding.
I think that using a converter is your only reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one quick way of handling this.  Not the most suitable, and a converter would likely be better.

```
public string DelayTimeText
{
    get
    {
        return _delayTimeText;
    }
    set
    {
        _delayTimeText = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
} 

public double DelayTime
{
    get
    {
        if (double.TryParse( DelayTimeText, out double val ));
        _delayTime = val;

        return _delayTime;
    }
}
```

You'd then bind to the Text property instead, and your calculations would rely on the TryParse, which would fall back to the previous value if it fails to parse.

Comment: I've tried your method, but I think it's flawed. When I try to type "0.7" into my View it converts into "7". It just ignores the numbers in front of the dot...